# Options to have variables in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I know that I can use Runner's Linux environment variables in GitHub Actions.

Do I have any other options to have variables and use them in workflow steps?

Comment: So you are asking if there is a way to have variables different than environment variables?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej, yes.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej, I am asking since I know BASH works with only environment variables. but BASH is too basic. Can we have PowerShell or Node variables persist between steps without keep assigning them to environment variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how variables are designed to work in GitHub Actions. I mean declared variables are mapped to env variables, like here:

```yaml
name: Show env

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
env:
  somevar: 'lastvar'
jobs:
  show:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Is variable exported?
        run: |
          echo "${{ env.somevar }}"
```

However, you can't use them everywhere - please check this [topic](https://github.community/t/how-to-set-and-access-a-workflow-variable/17335):

```yaml
env:
  pluginId: 'plugin-fn-xml-node'

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - ${{env.pluginId}}/**
      - .github/workflows/**
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - ${{env.pluginId}}/**
      - '.github/workflows/**'

jobs:
  build:
    env:
      working-directory: ${{env.pluginId}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x]

    steps:
```

This will not work because you can't use workflow variable at job level.

So if you define variable at workflow level you should be able to use it across steps.

I added also dynamically set variable based on [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable)

```yaml
env:
  somevar: 'lastvar'
jobs:
  show:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Is variable exported?
        run: |
          echo "${{ env.somevar }}"
          echo "action_state=yellow" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: PowerShell script
        # You may pin to the exact commit or the version.
        # uses: Amadevus/pwsh-script@25a636480c7bc678a60bbf4e3e5ac03aca6cf2cd
        uses: Amadevus/pwsh-script@v2.0.0
        continue-on-error: true
        with: 
          # PowerShell script to execute in Actions-hydrated context
          script: | 
            Write-Host $env:somevar
            Write-Host $env:action_state
      - name: Read exported variable
        run: |
          echo "$action_state"
          echo "${{ env.action_state }}"
```

Comment: How create a variable in one step and use it in another step? GitHub seems use Environment Variables diffrent than noraml shell scripts.

Comment: Please check this https://github.community/t/support-saving-environment-variables-between-steps/16230/9