# using a template file which consists of variables in github actions

Tags: github-actions

I am pretty new to GA but learning very fast.

I have read the question on this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64919507/options-to-have-variables-in-github-actions) and it is very useful. Coming from using Azure devops, I want to know if there is a way to define environment variables in a file which can be version controlled etc.

with yaml pipelines in Azure devops, I can do this.

```
variables:
  - name: BicepFilePath
    value: $(Build.Repository.Name)\BICEP\${{ parameters.project }}.bicep
  - name: ParametersFilePath
    value: $(Build.Repository.Name)\BICEP\${{ parameters.project }}.json
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'dev') }}:
    - template: vars/dev/${{ parameters.project }}.yml
```

Within the file, it has the following contents.

```
variables:
  resGroupName: my-rg
```

In the example above, If the env parameter has a value of `dev` I can load up `project.dev.yml` which has a lot of environment specific variables that will be useful for my pipeline. I do not want to declare this within the github action file, I have read up on how environment variables work on github actions, and it could be that I am on the free plan, perhaps this is why I cant create an environment and supply variables etc, however I do like the template file as it ensures I can have one per environment and version control it.

Any thoughts on a similar solution please

Comment: Sounds like a use case for [`jobs.<job_id>.environment`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idenvironment).